# Unreal Engine does not launch- problem 0xc0000005

Tags: unreal-engine4

I've recently installed Unreal Engine 4, but I can't launch it. It always shows a window of following content: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application".

I've looked through the Internet, but the problem remains. I've tried:

- updating drivers
- reinstalling Unreal Engine
- deleting updates of Windows
- reinstalling Visual Studio
- checking for malware

Comment: does your machine meet the minimum requirements:  https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Recommended_Hardware

Comment: Does it crash while just opening an empty project? Or only when you open an existing project?

Comment: Yes. I've looked through tge requirements, I meet both hardware and software.

Comment: What about not opening- I couldn't launch it a single time yet and had no possibility tonstart a project. It crashes BEFORE even the project choosing menu arrives

Comment: I hate to say, I had the same exact problem, and the cuz was one of windows security updates where I was too stupid to clean it up and cleaning all restore points.

What I've done is run the engine as admin, its only way it start, however, what make things worse, when it started I cannot drag and drop inside the engine anymore bec it will crash.

ended up I had to reinstall the window, and become too careful to any available updates.

Comment: I' ve seen through all updates mentioned in the Internet, but no, it does not work. Gonna try launching as admin, but I doubt if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Epic Games Launcher, open the unreal engine library tab then select your current engine version, click on the drop down menu and choose the verify option, this will verify if any file is missing from your device related to unreal engine, I hope this helps.